# Python запуск файла из командной строки

Tags: python, консоль

Пытаюсь запустить файл из командной строки. таким образом:
python filename.py
Не запускается.

```
Python: can't open file 'filename.py':   [Errno 2] No such file or directory.
```

Дословно от автора:

> Не забывайте заменять слово «python» на полный путь к исполняемому
>   файлу интерпретатора, **если переменная окружения PATH у вас не
>   настроена**.

Да, если указать путь, то файл запускается. Но, если следовать логики автора, то можно и не указывать путь. Я правильно понял?
То есть, если всё настроено правильно, то слово `python` остается и через пробел пишем имя файла с расширением `.py`.

Вот мои настройки переменной окружения

```
PATH: C:\Python35\Scripts\;C:\Python35\
```

Именно по этому пути питон и находится.

Comment: Питон-то у вас находится, не находится скрипт для исполнения.

Comment: Попробуйте полный путь именно до скрипта указать.

Comment: Владимир, в смысле не находится скрипт для исполнения? Все там находится. Указывая путь он открывается.
Rihard Brugekhaim, да, когда указываю полный путь, то все работает. А так как у автора возможно?

Comment: Из какой книги пример? Вообще, последние версии Python при инсталляции предлагают изменить системные переменные. Попробуйте переустановить.

Comment: Марк Лутц. Изучаем питон 4-е издание.
Проблему выяснили. Нужно находится в папке модуля (скрипта).
Ответ от Alex_P ниже.

Answer (score 7):

Вам необходимо перейти в папку со скриптом.
(Пример: `cd C:\\Projects\py\Project1`, где полный путь до скрипта `C:\\Projects\py\Project1\filename.py`) Затем вписать вашу команду. (`python filename.py` )

Также есть 2-той вариант. Надо указать абсолютный путь до файла.
(Пример: `python "C:\\Projects\py\Project1\filename.py"` Кавычки нужны если в пути есть пробелы)

Comment: Почему-то автор не указал на то, что нужно находится в этой папке или я не внимательный. Спасибо.

Comment: ежели хотите использовать python filename.py из любого места, то вы можете добавить C:\\Projects\py\Project1\ в PATH. Но имхо это извращение.

Comment: Попробовал. Не запускается.